# How do I install Likewise 6 without an internet connection?

Tags: windows, likewise

Hi, I'm very new to linux, I'm using Ubuntu 11 alongside windows in my work and I cant download likewise directly from the software centre without joining the domain. My other option is to download it on my home pc and them make image of my computer but this will be too big to put on USB flash drive.

How do I install the likewise 6 (I have it downloaded) manually, without internet connection?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install software or packages without internet (offline)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Answer (score 1):

this should help you
http://www.likewise.com/docs/man/ch02.html